# Run Macro on CSV file that is stored in another file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a CSV file that I receive daily that I format using a macro that is stored in my personal macro file.  I am trying to create a vbs file that will run the macro on the CSV file via a scheduled task, but I am not having an luck.  Here is the vbs file:

```
Option Explicit

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\test.csv", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\Personal.xlsb!newsales"
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> C:\Users\dmcgettigan\Desktop\test.vbs(13, 3) Microsoft Excel: Cannot run the macro 'c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\Personal.xlsb!new sales'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For me it's working like that

```
  Dim xlApp 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  xlapp.workbooks.open("<Path to your PERSONAL.XLSB>")
  xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Test"  
  xlApp.Quit
```

The comment is also right, you can't have a blank in the name of the sub you want to run.

**Update** Without being able to test it your code should look like this

```
Option Explicit

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\test.csv", 0, True) 
  xlapp.workbooks.open("c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\Personal.xlsb")
  xlApp.Run "Personal.xlsb!newsales"
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: That will work to open my personal macro but I just need the macro that is in that file to run on test.csv file.

Comment: If you want to run a macro from personal.xlsb you first have to open it. Or how should I understand you remark?

Comment: That makes sense, but where would I put your code, before or after the existing code?

Comment: You have to re-write the existing code, at least a little bit.

Comment: What does no luck mean? No one can help you like this.

Comment: Tried the update and I am still receiving the same error messages.

Comment: I do not think that you get excatly the same error message. You did change this line `xlApp.Run "c:\users\dmcgettigan\desktop\Personal.xlsb!newsales"` to the two new lines I suggested, right? So, the question is at which line do you get an error message now and what is it?

Comment: Sorry the error message is slightly different, "C:\Users\dmcgettigan\Desktop\test.vbs(12, 3) Microsoft Excel: Cannot run the macro 'PERSONAL.xlsb!NewSales'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled" . Previously it said "(13,3)"

Comment: Then you need to look at the macro name closely in your vbs and xl file because I assume macros are enabled. Then there seems to be a typo somewhere. I only get this error message if I misspell the macro name either in the vbs script or in the xl file. And maybe you add an `xlApp.visible = true` to your script in order to see a little bit more.

Comment: I noticed that when I added `xlApp.visible = true` the file opened as read only, that could explain my dilemma, right?

Comment: UPDATE removed the `Workbooks.Open... True` argument so it is not read only, but it is still not running the macro.

Comment: I do not know what the macro `newsales` does but the error message is saying that the macro does not exist. IMO you have to check for this first before you speculate if the file was opened read-only or not.